# Add tooltip to GtkButton

Tags: button, gtk, tooltip

I want to add a tooltip to a GtkButton.
This seems like an easy thing to do, except I have no idea why is not working. What I have:
1)

```
GtkButton* button = gtk_button_new_with_label("button");   
gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(button, "tooltip text");
```

2)

```
GtkButton* button = gtk_button_new_with_label("button"); 
GtkTooltips *button_bar_tips = gtk_tooltips_new();
gtk_tooltips_set_tip(GTK_TOOLTIPS (button_bar_tips), 
                     button , "tooltip text", NULL);
```

Tried both with

```
gtk_widget_set_has_tooltip(button, true);
```

but still no luck. Any ideas? thks!

Comment: Have you tried: button.set_tooltip_text("tooltip text"); ? Here's some more info & example: http://learngtk.org/pygtk-tutorial/tooltip.html.

Comment: This is GTK+ so there are no objects.. What you wrote is the same as `gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text`

Comment: Maybe you can check the settings. What is the output of `gboolean has_tooltip = FALSE;
    gint wait_time = 0;
    GtkSettings * settings = gtk_settings_get_default ();
    g_object_get(settings, "gtk-enable-tooltips", &has_tooltip, "gtk-tooltip-timeout", &wait_time, NULL);
    printf("tooltip:%d time:%d\n", has_tooltip, wait_time);`. Also maybe you can check if `"has-tooltip"` property is set for the button `g_object_get(GTK_WIDGET(button), "has-tooltip", &has_tooltip, NULL);`

Comment: @another.anon.coward thks. The result from the first part is: `tooltip = 1 time = 500`. Now the has-tooltip gives 0. But from what I've read from [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkTooltip.html), we only need to set "has-tooltip" if we want to catch the signals, in order to elaborate the tooltip. But yes, I've tried this second method as well. It prints my cout inside the callback, but still can't make the tooltip appear..

Comment: Ok so the first set of output suggest that settings has not disabled tooltip display and you have to hover 500ms for tooltip window to appear. But second section is a little strange, if you create a widget and set the tooltip text this property should have been set to `TRUE` i.e. 1. Can you try creating a simple minimal example and check this (might work most likely) to be sure that this behavior is application specify? What happens when you explicitly set the property using `g_object_set_property` to TRUE? What about other buttons in different layouts or location in the code? Or other widgets

Comment: hum.. I'm trying to use `g_object_set_property`, but since I've never used this function, I don't know what to put in the third field, GValue.. and the `gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text` works flawlessly on other buttons in the code. I'm really lost in this one..

Comment: Try the following `GValue val = G_VALUE_INIT;
    g_value_init (&val, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN);
    g_value_set_boolean (&val, TRUE);
    g_object_set_property(button, "has-tooltip", &val);`, if other buttons are able to display the tooltip what is that you are doing different with this button?

Comment: Error: identifier "G_VALUE_INIT" is undefined :s I had already tried that.. Im running GTK+ 2.24.

Comment: And I tried to compare it with other buttons but can't really find the missing link.. One button works and is contained in a gtk_alignment inside a table. Other button doesn't work and is contained in a fixed_container inside a table. This button is directly inserted in the table. I have done a lot in GTK, that's why this is driving me crazy.

Comment: I know this is deprecated, but i think widget tooltips come from here so in [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/x810.html) it says: _Widgets that do not receive events (widgets that do not have their own window) will not work with tooltips._ Maybe this is my problem, though I don't know if the widgets have their own window or not.. (I thought they all have, since they are ultimatly contained in the program window).

Comment: That is strange, `G_VALUE_INIT` is in `gvalue.h` which should have been included. Try to add `gobject-2.0` package to the build (or explicitly include `gvalue.h`). Did you happen to take the setting out of your current application and create a minimal program with same widget/arrangement and see the same behavior? Widget in a fixed should not have behaved any different, anything different with table entry for fixed or with fixed?

Comment: You can use [`gtk_widget_get_has_window`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-has-window) to find out if widget has its own window. As mentioned in the [GtkTooltips description](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkTooltips.html#GtkTooltips.description) if the widget has no window use `GtkEventBox` ... *but as you have noted this is deprecated*. You don't have to add any event box. If button were to be at fault then it should not have worked anywhere. Possibly some changes have been made to parent widget(s). Please try to reproduce this with minimal program.

Comment: Well.. I will not be able to test it, nor work with it anymore. I'm pretty sure this was some kind of mix of strange things (and maybe some bug, since GTK is already in the 3rd version). Anyway I'll accept  @user2389519's answer, since in most of the cases will do. Thank you all for the tips and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, GtkTooltips are deprecated now so let skip option 2), as for option 1) it looks completely right to me ...

So first, make sure you dont mix both approaches, maybe this is a problem...

Comment: You're right about GtkTooltips, which was deprecated by GtkTooltip. But anyway, I've made sure option 1) is all by itself, but nothing happens..

Comment: weird thing is this is working for me with a label:  
`GtkTooltips * _tooltip= gtk_tooltips_new();`  `gtk_tooltips_set_tip(_tooltip, label, "text", NULL);`

Comment: I am sorry, I have no more ideas, I can only say, that in my gimp plugins I am using only gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text() function and it works without problems. So no other *tooltip* functions at all. But the plugin is not a standalone program so maybe something more is really needed...

Comment: This is not true my friend. The gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text function is not deprecated, and neither is GtkTooltip. What is deprecated is the usage of tooltip windows. To quote the GTK3 to GTK4 migration guide, "Tooltips no longer use GtkWindows in GTK 4".

https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#stop-using-custom-tooltip-windows

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed GtkWidget and GtkButton:

```
GtkButton* button = gtk_button_ne*emphasized text*w_with_label("button");   
gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text(button, "tooltip text");
```

see? gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text() expects that the first parameter is GtkWidget, not GtkButton, your compiler(GCC?) should have throw warning, like this:

```
tooltips.c:23:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]*emphasized text*
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkapplication.h:27:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:31,
                 from tooltips.c:1:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:858:12: note: expected ‘struct GtkWidget *’ but argument is of type ‘struct GtkButton *’
```

Below is my example code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *button, *window, *vbox;
  GtkButton *button2;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Tool Tip Test");
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, 200, 200);
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 5);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Click me");
  gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text (button, "Tooltip of button");
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, TRUE, TRUE, 5);

  button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("No, click me");
  gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text (GTK_WIDGET (button2), "Tooltip of button2");
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), GTK_WIDGET (button2), TRUE, TRUE, 5);


  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}
```

If you remove GTK_WIDGET() from:

```
  gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text (GTK_WIDGET (button2), "Tooltip of button2");
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), GTK_WIDGET (button2), TRUE, TRUE, 5);
```

My GCC will throw these warnings.

So it is a good way that ALL the widget varaibles in Gtk shall be inited as GtkWidget type, and then redefine them as other types when needed, using GTK_BUTTON(), GTK_CONTAINER, GTK_BOX(), GTK_WINDOW()...

Comment: lol @LiuLang thank you for all that explanation, but in my code I have always GtkWidget, it was a typo sorry And I'm pretty sure your code would work, if my program was that simple.

Comment: First of all, great example - thanks for contributing to the community of GTK learners. 

Unfortunately, this is code does not compile in GTK4 (since that's not what it was written for). 

I will link to a Gist in this thread with a simple tooltip example if nobody else does it first.

Answer (score 0):

I think since no GTK version was specified, GTK4 friends may look for a GTK4 example here.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/angstyloop/4aa38d2fbf046c3ee555cf4941a58dce) is a GTK4 example that uses [gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Widget.set_tooltip_text.html).

Hover over the button to see the tooltip appear.

```
/** tooltip.c   
 *
 * COMPILE
 *
 * gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk4` -o tooltip tooltip.c `pkg-config --libs gtk4`
 *
 * RUN
 *
 * ./tooltip
 */

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

// Not strictly necessary, but here for maximum portability.
#if GLIB_CHECK_VERSION(2, 74, 0)
static int app_flags = G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS;
#else
static int app_flags = G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE;
#endif

static void activate( GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data )
{
    GtkWidget *window, *button;

    window = gtk_application_window_new( app );

    // You can add tooltip text to any GtkWidget. I used a GtkButton.
    // You could just as easily use a GtkLabel by itself, or a GtkBox.
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label( "hover here" );

    gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text( button, "hello world" );

    gtk_window_set_child( GTK_WINDOW( window ), button );

    gtk_widget_show(window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    puts("hover over the window to see the tooltip");

    app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", app_flags);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
}
```